# Error when trying to filter a list of dictionaries with a specific value i get error

Tags: python, mysql

I get the data from a table from an mysql database.
I'm trying to filter a list of dictionaries with a specific value. When I execute  the code I get the following error:

Using IDE = PyCharm.

> **Error:**
>
> [x.append(k) for k in lst_cmp_helpdesk_dic if "Doble" in k[key]]
>
> **TypeError:** argument of type 'int' is not iterable

```
import mysql.connector


def test_initialize_test_data():

    global lst_cmp_helpdesk
    global lst_cmp_helpdesk_dic

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='User', password='Password', host='Srv Name or IP', database='DataBase Name')
    try:
        cursor_dic = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True,buffered=True)
        cursor_dic.execute("select * from Table_Name")
        lst_cmp_helpdesk_dic = cursor_dic.fetchall()
    
        x = []
        for key in lst_cmp_helpdesk_dic[0].keys():
            [x.append(k)for k in lst_cmp_helpdesk_dic if "Search_Text" in k[key]]
            count = len(([dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in x])]))
        print("\n Length = " + str(count))
    finally:
        cnx.close()
```

Comment: Rather, `k` is an integer and trying to index with `[key]` is invalid

Comment: Ah, you're right - that would give a `not subscriptable` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying

```
"Search_Text" in k[key]
```

but `k[key]` returns an int. Therefore, you can't iterate on it with `in`.

one thing you could is actually print out `lst_cmp_helpdesk_dic[0].keys()` and make sure that it contains names that you want to compare against `"Search_text"`

Comment: Thank you, i figure it out the value return was the Id of the item in the table. I add the str() function to convert all data to string and it solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's problem to accessing the data from database. It may be different datatype in database and you are accessing in different format. I suggest please check your database once.